# what does prototype mean in clustering?

Tags: machine-learning

I am studying decision trees and machine learning. I have encountered with this word several time. Although, it seems that it not an important concept, I cannot understand this word in machine learning literature. For example:

> if the test does not significantly satisfy the criteria, then it creates a leaf and computes the prototype of the instances belonging to the leaf"
>   .

what does prototype in this sentence mean?

According to Wikipedia:

> A prototype is an early sample, model, or release of a product built to test a concept or process or to act as a thing to be replicated or learned from.

But it does not make sense.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an addition of the technique on k-prototypes

Answer (score 2):

A prototype is an element of the data space that represents a group of elements. On the context of clustering (e.g. under a leaf), a cluster prototype serves to characterize the cluster, their elements. You can have a look at [Cluster analysis: basic concepts and algorithms](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch8.pdf) for instance, taken from [Introduction to data mining](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/index.php).

In a more specific acceptation, it denotes an instance of clustering for combined numerical and categorical values, in the spirit of k-means, k-modes, k-medians, see for instance [Into the world of clustering algorithms: k-means, k-modes and k-prototypes](https://amva4newphysics.wordpress.com/2016/10/26/into-the-world-of-clustering-algorithms-k-means-k-modes-and-k-prototypes/comment-page-1/):

> For numerical and categorical data, another extension of these
>   algorithms exists, basically combining k-means and k-modes. It is
>   called k-prototypes.

Comment: the link does not work. could you correct it?

Comment: Link is corrected